# Localization with ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, multilingual

I'm trying to create my website with localization using mvc3 Razor, and I have no idea how to do that. Is there someone who can tell me how to do that?

Comment: Multilanguage? Do you mean Localization, or doing templates in C# and VB.NET?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Sorry if this question's so annoying. I'm a newbie and dun know what that's called